# Datagrid ObservableCollection for one row wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to populate a datagrid with itemsource={Binding Model}. 
This is not working out. It seems as the datagrid does not understand how to display these properties.

An easy but silly workaround works great:

In viewmodel:

```
Props= new ObservableCollection<MonitoringBinaryModel>();
_Model = new MonitoringBinaryModel(name);
Props.Add(_Model);
```

Then in xaml

```
itemsource={Binding Props}
```

Seems silly to create an observablecollection when its only suppose to hold one item. Is there a better way to make any type of instance observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid is designed to display a collection of objects of same type. Collection is a must. If you want DataGrid to show a content of your model, you need to obey former's design, by either using ObservableCollection or implementing a bunch of interfaces which would allow your viewmodel's properties to be retrieved in 'collection way'.

I used to have a bunch of models implementing ITypedList interface back in Windows Forms time - it wasn't a simple exercise to say the truth, so if I were you I'd rather go for either way:

- Wrap model into any collection - exactly as you've stated
- Replace data grid with container grid plus a number of direct bindings, like this:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Prop1"/>
  ...
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
  ```

Comment: Ok, then I guess I will continue using the workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) property is of type `IEnumarable` so until your `MonitoringBinaryModel` implement `IEnumerable` binding will not work.

Again because `ItemsSource` is `IEnumerable` you should provide `IEnumerable` as binding source. So there is no need to make yout `Props` as `ObservableCollection`. You can use ordinary `List<>`, or anything implementing `IEnumerable` with your single `MonitoringBinaryModel`:

```
_Model = new MonitoringBinaryModel(name);
Props = new List<MonitoringBinaryModel> { _Model };
```

Other option is to use `CompositeCollection` inside your XAML:

```
<DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <Binding Path="_Model"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</DataGrid.ItemsSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

reusable wrapper via converter:

```
public class ItemsSourceConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // doesn't allow to add new rows in DataGrid
        return Enumerable.Repeat(value, 1);            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

usage in xaml

add converter to resourses:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:ItemsSourceConverter x:Key="ItemWrapper"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use converter resourse with binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model, Converter={StaticResource ItemWrapper}}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

or

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model, Converter={StaticResource ItemWrapper}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```