# Get Ancestor Source in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I am trying to get the ancestor ItemsControl.ItemTemplate source as my DataGrid source but i could not handle the case. I tried the following case in my xaml. But it did not work and datagrid is empty.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" FlowDirection=" RightToLeft">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <DataGrid FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                            ItemsSource="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemTemplate}}}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Password}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Expander.Header>
           </Expander>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Accounts property implementation is like:

```
public List<User> Accounts = new List<User>();
Accounts.Add(new User("userName1","password1"));
Accounts.Add(new User("userName2","password2"));
```

And my User.cs is like:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public string UserName{get; set;}
        public string Password{get; set;}


       public UserAccount(string userName, string password)
       {
          UserName = userName;
          Password = password;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this code doesn't create a binding

```
ItemsSource="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemTemplate}}}"
```

also ancestor type is incorrect.

try this Binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Accounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

or use ElementName:

```
<ItemsControl Name="LstAccounts" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">
```

and

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Accounts, ElementName=LstAccounts}"
```

---

*code above fixes binding, but produces unexpected results. here is a solution to show a single object in a DataGrid*

for ItemSource binding I created a converter ([my own older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34752584/1506454))

```
public class ItemsSourceConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // doesn't allow to add new rows in DataGrid
        return Enumerable.Repeat(value, 1).ToArray();            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and here is modified ItemsControl. Converter is stored in resources and used in ItemsSource binding. DataGrid autogenerates columns

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:ItemsSourceConverter x:Key="Enumerator"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" FlowDirection=" RightToLeft">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <DataGrid FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource Enumerator}}"/>
                </Expander.Header>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

here is a screenshot

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: This binding is working but the problem is it binds all the items inside the Accounts. The thing is, i only want to bind every item to different expanderHeader. I mean, this binding is working like DataGridSource = Accounts     But I want something like DataGridSource = Account

Comment: @stackerflow, i reread the question and got confused why ItemTemplate contains `Expander` and `DataGrid` (in header) when items is a simple User object with only 2 properties. Maybe use DataGrid instead of ItemsControl? like this: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Accounts"> <DataGrid.Columns> <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" >
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Password}" /> </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>`

Comment: Well i have some editable textboxes and item related menus under expander content which i removed while posting the question for not confusing the people with overload information. To be clear: I just want to get item context not the list context inside expander. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: ok, if Header should display info of a single User, i would not use DataGrid (it is really confusing to me, though possible even for a single item). i would use a panel with some controls, e.g : `<Expander.Header> <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" /> <TextBlock Text="{Binding Password}" /> </StackPanel> </Expander.Header>`. this is primitive of course, needs improvement like captions, but shows the idea

Comment: The point is StackPanel is very primitive and designing it's looking a very complex for me. I just like the visualisation of the datagrid that's why i choose it. If you have any solution about converting the stackpanel visualisation to dataGridRow style then it will be quite usefull also